# WooCommerce Extension - applicable hook when redirect to 'Pay' endpoint

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm integrating a WooCommerce payment gateway plugin and have a requirement to embed the gateway in an iframe. I'm redirecting with the below code to the `Pay` (the `/order-pay` route by default) endpoint where I'd like to include the iframe where the payment process will continue.

*Does anyone know of an applicable hook in which I load the necessary JS scripts to initialise the iframe on the order-pay template?*

```
function process_payment( $order_id ) {
  global $woocommerce;
  $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
  $order->update_status( 'pending-payment', __( 'Awaiting payment', 'some-domain' ) );

  return array(
    'result'   => 'success',
    'redirect' => $order->get_checkout_payment_url( $on_checkout = true )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an appropriate WooCommerce hook for the `order-pay` page. What I decided to do is add an action for the `wp_enqueue_scripts` and only load my scripts if the applicable route is active.

In my plugin constructor:

```
function __contstruct {
  // other stuff
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'load_my_order_pay_scripts' ) );
}
```

The function to load my scripts:

```
public function load_my_order_pay_scripts() {
  if( !is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-pay' ) ) return;

  global $wp;
  $order_id = $wp->query_vars['order-pay'];
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js-sdk', 'http://my.cdn.com/my-js-sdk.js', true );
  wp_register_script( 'my-plugin-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/js/my-plugin-script.js', true );
  wp_localize_script( 'my-plugin-script', 'params', $this->script_parameters, true ); // I need to pass my script some data
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-plugin-script', array('my-js-sdk'), true ); // my plugin's JS is dependent on my SDK
}
```